# AngularJS navigation bar directive with a refresh button

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I looked online for a solution but I couldn't find one that suites my needs. Tried [this](http://suhairhassan.com/2013/10/21/refactoring-to-angularjs-directive.html#.UwIPXPldVyx) and looked into [this](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/directives.html) with no help.

My case is, I designed a mobile app with AngularJS and the app has a navigation bar. Every page has this navigation bar because of that, I decided to move the code to a directive. The navigation bar has a button inside of it and this button will be used to force a refresh on the app's data (similar to facebook's pull to refresh). The navigation bar is displayed in all pages and whenever the user are, if he click's on the button the app has to execute an update and redirects to a certain page to display the results.

The problem is, since the navigation is inside of a directive and the user can click on any screen how do I manage capturing the click on the button, calling the refresh function and redirecting to a page?

Here is my directive and one of the pages I used it.

```
myAppDirectives.directive('headerMenu', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: 'partials/templates/header-menu.html'
};
});

<div class="topcoat-navigation-bar">
<div class="topcoat-navigation-bar__item left quarter">
    <a class="topcoat-icon-button--quiet" snap-toggle>
        <span class="topcoat-icon icon-menu-stack"></span>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="topcoat-navigation-bar__item right three-quarters">
    <a class="topcoat-icon-button--quiet" href="" > <!-- THIS IS THE REFRESH BUTTON -->
        <span class="topcoat-icon icon-refresh"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Page example:

```
<div header-menu></div>
<div> MAIN CONTENT </div>
```

Thank you!
**Update 2:** I do appreciate the answers about using ui-router. Since my project is already running and almost ready, structural changes like that are not in question. The accepted answer was the one that solved my problem although the others might fit better other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put a `ngClick` on this button:

```
<a class="topcoat-icon-button--quiet" ng-click="redirect()">
```

And provide a redirect function on the directive's scope:

```
myAppDirectives.directive('headerMenu', function() {
  return {
      scope:{},
      restrict: 'A',
      templateUrl: 'partials/templates/header-menu.html',
      link: function(scope){
        scope.redirect = function(){
          // redirect to...
        }
      }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When I need to do this, I use `ui-router`, and create a view hierarchy that keeps the navigation bar loaded for every page. That way I can have for example, a `navbar.html` partial, and a state setup like the following:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('header', url: '', templateUrl: 'header.html', controller: 'HeaderCtrl' })
    .state('header.page', url: '/somepage', templateUrl: 'page.html', controller: 'PageCtr' })
    .state( ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Matt Way, `ui-router` is great solution for syncing nav bars. Although, for my projects I've been using `Multiple Named Views` config with ui-router, and your able to get real-time sync between main app interactions and the nav bar, negating the need for "refresh buttons".

In addition, if the user wants to return to the previous page, ui-router will maintain app "state", forms/UX/etc will still be as before.

Have a look at the ui-router wiki https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views.

Basic demo with header sync http://plnkr.co/edit/kYPGZw?p=preview

Basic multi view config (viewC is Nav):

```
$stateProvider
.state('state1', {
  url: "/",
  views: {
    "viewA": {
      template: "1st Tab, index.viewA"
    },
    "viewB": {
      template: '1st Tab, index.viewB<br><a ui-sref=".list">Show List</a>' +
                '<div ui-view="viewB.list"></div>'
    },
    "viewC": {
      template: '1st Tab, index.viewC <div ui-view="viewC.list"></div>'
    }
  }
})
.state('state1.list', {
  url: 'list',
  views: {
    "viewB.list": {
      template: '<h2>Nest list viewB</h2><ul>' +
                '<li ng-repeat="thing in tab1things">{{thing}}</li></ul>',
      controller: 'Tab1ViewBCtrl',
      data: {}
    },
    "viewC.list": {
      template: '1st Tab, list.viewC'
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I appreciate your examples, Didn't know about ui-router, looks pretty interesting. But in my case, my navigation bar is more like a toolbar. It is not meant to use like navigation links. It is just a toolbar with a "snap" and a refresh button where the user can force the app to get the latest data from the server at any view. The redirect behavior is just because the method where I get the latest data is my main controller so I had to redirect the user to that view.